# Where can I find documentation for the pycups module for CUPS printing?

Tags: python, documentation, cups

I am using the python cups module to list the available destinations. And everything work perfectly. I've installed the `pycups` using `sudo apt-get install pycups`.

```
import cups

conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
for p in printers:
    print(p)
    print(printers[p],["device-uri"])
```

The problem is that I am not finding a **documentation** for this module and what are the methods that can be used so can implement other functionalities.

Do you have an idea where I can find the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. There is one [example](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/pycups/blob/master/examples/cupstree.py) in their github and that's all I could find. You should probably poke around with a python debugger to learn how the library works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32245612)

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in `help` function in python interpreter:

```py
>>> import cups
>>> help(cups)
# shows auto-generated documentation for cups module
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in help function mentioned in the above answer.
Here is an example of printing a file using pycups

```
 |  printFile(...)
 |      printFile(printer, filename, title, options) -> integer
 |      
 |      Print a file.
 |      
 |      @type printer: string
 |      @param printer: queue name
 |      @type filename: string
 |      @param filename: local file path to the document
 |      @type title: string
 |      @param title: title of the print job
 |      @type options: dict
 |      @param options: dict of options
 |      @return: job ID
 |      @raise IPPError: IPP problem
```

printFile needs 4 parameters.
I passed an empty dictionary because it was necessary and also I am using the first available printer

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection ()
printers = conn.getPrinters ()
# printers is a dictionary containing information about all the printers available

emptyDict = {}
AvailablePrinters = list(printers.keys())
PrinterUsing = AvailablePrinters[0]
conn.printFile(PrinterUsing, "./FileName", "title", emptyDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for pycups-1.9.51: *[Documentation](http://nagyak.eastron.hu/doc/system-config-printer-libs-1.2.4/pycups-1.9.51/html/)*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35052694)

Answer (score 0):

About the options argument, I often use:
`{"sides": "two-sided-long-edge", "prettyprint": "True"}`

You can find other keys in man pages, "Common Job Options" section:
- `man lpr`
-  [localhost:631/help/man-lpr.html](http://localhost:631/help/man-lpr.html)